# Show that $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ is homogeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that $\mathbb{C}$ is homogeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ is homogeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\})$

Idea: A biholomorphic mapping of a domain D onto itself is called an automorphism of D. $Aut (D)$ is a group with respect to the composition of mappings and the
identity mapping is its neutral element.

A domain $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is called homogeneous
with respect to a subgroup $L$ of $Aut D$, if for every two points $z_1, z_2\in D$ there
is an automorphism $h\in L$ with $h(z_1) =z_2 $.

For Show that $\mathbb{C}$ is homogeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C})$ just keep in mind $Aut(\mathbb{C})={\{az+b:a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}, b \in\mathbb{C}}\}$ 
I don't know how to prove that $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ is homogeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\})$. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: What kind of automorphisms do we consider here? Preserving group structure? Field structure? Topological structure?

Comment: Given the tags I would guess it means automorphisms of complex manifolds, but this should still be stated explicitly.

Comment: @Wojowu A biholomorphic mapping of a domain D onto itself is called an automorphism of D. $Aut D$ is a group with respect to the composition of mappings and the
identity mapping is its neutral element.

Comment: What automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ do you know?

Comment: @Wojowu $az+b$ with $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$. But $Aut(\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\})$?

Comment: Let $f$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$: show that $1/(f(1/z)-f(1))$ has a removable singularity at $0$. As a consequence, $f(z)=O(z^n)$ at infinity for some $n$, so $f$ is a polynomial, so $f$ is affine.

Comment: For any $a\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, $z\mapsto az$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. You don't need to bother classifying *all* automorphisms, just those are enough.

Comment: @Wojowu- Suppose $w\in\mathbb{C}$ then $h(z)=z+w$ is automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ Then as $h(0)=w$, the orbit ${\{h(0):h(z)=z+w}\}$ fills  $\mathbb{C}$; $\mathbb{C}$ is homegeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C})$, is correct? In the other hand Suppose $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ then $h(z)=wz$ is automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ Then as $h(1)=w$, the orbit ${\{h(1):h(z)=z+w}\}$ fills  $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$; $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ is homegeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C})$$w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $w\in\mathbb{C}$ then $h(z)=z+w$ is automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ Then as $h(0)=w$, the orbit ${\{h(0):h(z)=z+w}\}$ fills $\mathbb{C}$ hence $\mathbb{C}$ is homegeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C})$.

In the other hand Suppose $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ then $h(z)=wz$ is automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ Then as $h(1)=w$, the orbit ${\{h(1):h(z)=z+w}\}$ fills $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ hence $\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\}$ is homegeneous with respect $Aut(\mathbb{C}\setminus{\{0}\})$